# Making \addlinespace work with tabularray

Tags: booktabs, tabularray

I need to fix the following error after using `\addlinespace`

> Misplaced \noalign.
> \addlinespace ->\noalign
> {\ifnum 0=`}\fi @ifnextchar [{@addspace }{@addsp...
> l.25    \end
> {tblr}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray, booktabs}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
            width = 0.5\linewidth, colspec = {XX}, rowhead = 1,
            row{odd} = {gray!10}, row{even} = {gray!30}, row{1} = {blue!5},
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt]
        One & Two  \\
        \midrule
        1  &   2  \\
        3  &   4  \\
        5  &   6  \\
        7  &   8  \\
        9  &  10  \\
        \addlinespace
        11  &  12  \\
        13  &  14  \\
        15  &  16  \\
        17  &  18  \\
        19  &  20  \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may use `\SetRow{abovesep+=5pt}` there.

Comment: @L.J.R. How to make the separation have white color regardless the colors of the rows above and below? I need to do the same styling effect for the global key `rowsep+`.

Comment: Then you may write `\hline[white,5pt]`.

Comment: @L.J.R. I have off-topic question if you don't mind: I fail to control the vertical alignment of the rows contents using `cells={b}`, `rows={b}`, or `columns={b}` inside the table mandatory options. They have no effect at all; so, what should be done to have a control over the cells contents vertical alignment?

Comment: Better to ask a new question with details.

Comment: @L.J.R. I asked it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/605676/2288. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With version 2021N (2021-09-01) of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, you can use `\addlinespace` command with `booktabs` library.

Note that one half of the vertical space is added to the previous row and the other half is added to current row. This makes row colors look better.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  width = 0.5\linewidth, colspec = {XX}, rowhead = 1,
  row{odd} = {gray9!50}, row{even} = {gray9}, row{1} = {blue9},
}
  \toprule[1.5pt]
    One & Two  \\
  \midrule
     1  &   2  \\
     3  &   4  \\
     5  &   6  \\
     7  &   8  \\
     9  &  10  \\
  \addlinespace
    11  &  12  \\
    13  &  14  \\
    15  &  16  \\
    17  &  18  \\
    19  &  20  \\
  \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]