# tabularray: How to control the vertical alignment of the cells contents?

Tags: tabularray

For the following, I would like to understand

1- what `rows={b}`, `columns={b}`, or `cells={b}` should actually do

2- why none of them makes the contents of the rows bottom-aligned as instructed by the option `b`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=75mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}[long, caption = {The Caption II}]
        {
            rows = {5.0ex, b},
            cells = {b},
            columns = {b},
            hlines = {white,1.0pt},
            rulesep = 0pt,
            width = 0.5\linewidth,
            colspec = {XX}, 
            row{odd} = {blue!15}, 
            row{even} = {gray!15},
            rowhead = 1,
            row{1} = {red!20},
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt] 
        \hline[white,1.0pt]
        One & Two  \\
        \midrule
        \hline[white,1.0pt]
        1  &   2  \\
        3  &   4  \\
        5  &   6  \\
        7  &   8  \\
        9  &  10  \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer in the question [p,m and b columns in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35293/p-m-and-b-columns-in-tables/597283#597283). What you really want is `f` alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=75mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tblr}[long, caption = {The Caption II}]
        {
            rows = {5.0ex, f},
            hlines = {white,1.0pt},
            rulesep = 0pt,
            width = 0.5\linewidth,
            colspec = {XX}, 
            row{odd} = {blue!15}, 
            row{even} = {gray!15},
            rowhead = 1,
            row{1} = {red!20},
        }
        \toprule[1.5pt] 
        \hline[white,1.0pt]
        One & Two  \\
        \midrule
        \hline[white,1.0pt]
        1  &   2  \\
        3  &   4  \\
        5  &   6  \\
        7  &   8  \\
        9  &  10  \\
        \bottomrule[1.5pt]
    \end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]